# Need help understanding this article about templates

Tags: c++, templates

I was reading this article from this [page](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=388), so let me present the code:

```
template <class T> class D: typename C<T>::Base { //#1 error
    D(): typename C<T>::Base(typename C<T>::Base(0)) { } //#2 error, #3 correct
    typename C<T> f() { //#4 error
        typename C<T>::A* p; //#5 correct
        A<T>::B * n;
    }
};
class Q{
    typename C<long>::A * p; // #6 error
}
template <class T, class U> class R{
    typename C<long>::A * p; // #7 optional
}
```

`#3` is correct but I am trying to understand what the author is attempting to convey. He says:

> typename #3: correct. Here, typename is used for disambiguating the
>   **type of a parameter**. Without typename, the expression C::Base(0)
>   would be treated as a call to a function called Base. With the
>   typename prefix, C::Base(0) creates a temporary object of type
>   C::Base initialized with the argument 0.

Also, if you see a little above that part the author says:

> The typename keyword must prefix a dependent name when that name
>   satisfies the following three rules:
>
> 1.It appears inside a template
>
> 2.**It's qualified // i am unable to understand this line at all in conjunction with starting para of this quote**
>
> 3.It isn’t used in a base class specification or a member initialization
>   list.

I am unable to understand **this line** (#2 above) at all in conjunction with starting paragraph of this quote.  Can you explain what the author means?

Comment: I cleaned it up quite a bit and I moved what I **think** is the question out of the block quote.

Comment: @Kerrek : yes (read the bolded sentences?) , you saying this cause you haven't read it whole i think *grins*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Qualified" means that it is not in the same scope, but a subscope of the current one, which also depends on a template. For instance,

```
template <class T> struct C {
    typedef int b;
}
```

`b` is a qualified `id` when referenced in another template e.g

```
template<typename T> struct M {
    typename C<T>::b bb;
}
```

Relevant quote from the standard (§14.6.3):

> A qualified-id that refers to a type and in which the
>   nested-name-specifier depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2) shall
>   be prefixed by the keyword typename to indicate that the qualified-id
>   denotes a type, forming an elaborated-type-specifier (7.1.5.3).

And §14.6.2:

```
A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is dependent on a template-parameter is
assumed not to name a type unless the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
by the keyword typename. [Example:
    // no B declared here
    class X;
    template<class T> class Y {
        class Z; // forward declaration of member class
        void f() {
            X* a1; // declare pointer to X
            T* a2; // declare pointer to T
            Y* a3; // declare pointer to Y<T>
            Z* a4; // declare pointer to Z
            typedef typename T::A TA;
            TA* a5; // declare pointer to T’s A
            typename T::A* a6; // declare pointer to T’s A
            T::A* a7; // T::A is not a type name:
            // multiply T::A by a7; ill-formed,
            // no visible declaration of a7
            B* a8; // B is not a type name:
            // multiply B by a8; ill-formed,
            // no visible declarations of B and a8
        }
    };
—end example]
```

And §14.6.7:

```
Within the definition of a class template or within the definition of a member of a class template, the keyword
typename is not required when referring to the unqualified name of a previously declared member
of the class template that declares a type. The keyword typename shall always be specified when the
member is referred to using a qualified name, even if the qualifier is simply the class template name.
[Example:
    template<class T> struct A {
        typedef int B;
        A::B b; // ill-formed: typename required before A::B
        void f(A<T>::B); // ill-formed: typename required before A<T>::B
        typename A::B g(); // OK
    };

The keyword typename is required whether the qualified name is A or A<T> because A or A<T> are synonyms
within a class template with the parameter list <T>. ]
```

Comment: you answered the question which is after `also` word , can you please tell what author is saying in template `typename #3`

Comment: @Mr.Anubis if you left of `typename` and just did `C<T>::Base(0)`, it would think you were trying to call the function `C<T>::Base` with the argument of `0`, when really you are trying to _construct an instance of_ `C<T>::Base` passing `0` to its constructor.

Comment: but constructor is function which we need to call to create a object , so what's the difference?

Comment: @x4d3 the constructor is not a function in the normal sense because it doesn't return anything. And you have to get to it through a name that could be a type name (which would make it a ctor) or a function name. So you have to tell the compiler what you want to do to resolve the ambiguity.

Comment: Can you please explain your this line bit more? -> `And you have to get to it through a name that could be a type name (which would make it a ctor) or a function name.`

Comment: @x4d3 the name `C<T>::Base` is both a valid function name and a valid type name. The compiler does not check to see which one it is, so _you have to tell it_ that it is a type by `typename`, so it will know that `C<T>::Base` is the name of a type, and putting parentheses after it like `C<T>::Base(0)` is calling the constructor for that type.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help, but an example of template usage:

```
template<typename TemplateVar>
class SimpleTemplate
{
    public:
        TemplateVar Item;

        void SetItem(TemplateVar &ItemCopy);
        TemplateVar &GetItem();
};

template<typename TemplateVar>
void SimpleTemplate<TemplateVar>::SetItem(TemplateVar &ItemCopy)
{
    Item = ItemCopy;
    return;
}

template<typename TemplateVar>
TemplateVar &SimpleTemplate<TemplateVar>::GetItem()
{
    return Item;
}

int main(int ArgC, char *ArgV[])
{
    SimpleTemplate<char> Test;
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to do whatever you want with the code (even sell it, if you can).

Comment: +1 for `Feel free to do whatever you want with the code (even sell it, if you can).`